# Question mark visible instead of application icon in the doc

Tags: macos, dock, ventura

I have installed Android Studio some days ago and I can see it is visible as a question mark instead of an actual icon.
(I have download Android Studio from the official website)

The strange thing I have noticed is that if I click or click with two fingers on my mouse pad it starts visible the actual icon.

I'm using Macbook air M2,
macOS: Ventura 13.3.1 (a)

[image: Dock without Android Studio icon]

If I click on the question mark or show options it is visible

[image: Dock with Android Studio icon]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `killall Dock` to force that process to re-launch.  You could remove the ? icon by ctrl- or right-clicking on it and choosing "Options > Remove From Dock," then dragging the app back into the Dock.

You should also consider updating to the latest version of macOS, either Ventura 13.6 or Sonoma 14.0 - security improvements, but also plenty of minor bug fixes.

Comment: Thanks, i just updated macOs to Sonoma 14.0 and it worked.